# How to filter prometheus query by label value using greater-than

Tags: prometheus, promql

If I have matrics like this

```
my_metric{deployTime="1603284798",foo='bar'}
my_metric{deployTime="1603284799",foo='bar2'}
my_metric{deployTime="1603284800",foo='bar3'}
```

And I want to get only the metrics where the timestamp is greater than some value, how can I do it?

I was thinking of:

```
count by (deployTime, foo) (my_metric{deployTime > "1603284799", foo=~".*"})
```

but of course, this doesn't work as labels are strings. So what are my options to filter by label value if I want to use the greater than operator?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly but, do you have a label called "timestamp"? This seems to be unnecessary.

I think you can achieve what you want with the following query:

```
count by (foo) (timestamp(my_metric)>1603284799)
```

UPDATE

After you have clarified your question the answer is: unfortunately you can't query for labels using "greater than", "less than", etc.

Comment: I should be more specific the timestamp in the metric is not a current timestamp is a time stamp set in the metric at some point in time. The example you provided seems to get me the timestamp when the metric occurred. Thanks for helping I will rename the field in my question to avoid confusion

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with [label_value()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_value) function from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html):

```
count by (deployTime, foo) (
  label_value(my_metric{foo=~"..."}, "deployTime") > 1603284799
)
```

MetricsQL also supports [now()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#now) function, which can simplify calculations for timestamp relative to the current time. For example, the following query would filter out time series with `deployTime` values older than one hour from now:

```
label_value(my_metric{foo=~"..."}, "deployTime") > now() - 1h
```